# Error while creating table using select statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a table using a select statement but i am getting the following error.

Note: I ran the select statement without create and it worked

```
CREATE TABLE shipments_temp AS 
  (SELECT Concat('W', RIGHT([calendar year week], 2), '-', 
                      LEFT([calendar year week], 4)), 
          [market], 
          [base product code], 
          Sum([sell-in history]) AS Shipments 
   FROM   apac_092016_092018_shipments 
   GROUP  BY Concat('W', RIGHT([calendar year week], 2), '-', 
                         LEFT([calendar year week], 4)), 
             [market], 
             [base product code]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server does not support `create table as`.  Instead, use `into`:

```
select concat('W', right([Calendar Year Week],2), '-', LEFT([Calendar Year Week], 4)
             ) as column_whatever, -- you need a column alias
      [Market], [Base Product Code], sum([Sell-in History]) as Shipments
into Shipments_Temp
from APAC_092016_092018_Shipments
Group by concat('W', right([Calendar Year Week], 2), '-', LEFT([Calendar Year Week], 4)),
         [Market], [Base Product Code]);
```

You also need to name the first column for the target table.